# iPhone to activate personal Hotspot based on position

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc, ibeacon

This is more a general question rather than to a specific programming language. I can't seem to find any solution or idea how to get this working.

The situation is the following:
Currently im working on my Car-tablet Install (Basicly a Android Tablet replacing the OEM Navigation). The Tablet is hard-wired into the dash and will stay there aslong as I own the car.

I would want the tablet to get access to the internet permanently when im in the car. The tablet itself doesnt have a simslot and i dont want to spend money on either a different tablet or a 2nd simcard that would provide me direct internet access via 3G.

My solution would be to create a Hotspot on my Iphone (5) and connect the Android Tablet (Lenovo IdeaTab A-1000F) to it. This already works but I do have to activate the Hotspot manually everytime i get into my car. As the car moves (obviously.. :)), a specific GPS Range for actions is not a great solution for me.

So the question is: Is there a way (i.e. with Beacons or NFC) to activate my Iphone Hotspot automatically as soon as I get in the car?

You dont need to provide a fully working answer but already Ideas or examples would help me out. I just feel kind of lost without ideas at the moment as it looks like iBeacons arent able to perform actions the way I would need them to and NFC is not supported by iPhone without further modifications..? (Correct me if im wrong here)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Android devices cannot transmit as iBeacons as of Android 4.4 (they can only receive) so you cannot use it to wake up your iPhone and put it into hotspot mode.  However, you could install a cheap dedicated USB powered iBeacon using the same power source as your tablet.  My company sells [RadBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/radbeacon/) which would do the job nicely.

You could then write an app for iOS that would wake up whenever near your car. (See any iOS iBeacon tutorial).  You would put in code to turn on the hotspot when the iOS `didEnterRegion` method fires.

Before you go to far with this, make sure iOS even allows you to turn on a hotspot programmatically at all.  If not, automating this will be a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

Interested idea. If your tablet support iBeacon and is possible to create iBeacon region,  you need a little app on iPhone that using private api turn hot-spot On. But is can not be fully automatically you still need to wake iPhone at least.

Comment: Waking up the phone is not the problem; assuming it's not hard powered down, the beacon signal can do that.  What is more doubtful is an app being able to automatically start the hot spot, but you seem to be proposing a workaround for that.

Comment: @sage444 : how to turn on ios hotspot? can you please tell any  private api  to turn hot-spot.